# C# Regex matching two numbers divided by specific string and surrounded by brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a .NET [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) pattern that matches the following:

- string starts with the `[` character
- followed by an **integer** or **decimal** number
- followed by `..` (space character, dot, dot, space character)
- followed by an **integer** or **decimal** number
- followed by the last character of the string which is `)`

*- the decimal numbers have a decimal separator, the `.` character

*- the integer numbers or the integer value of the decimal numbers should have a maximum of 4 digits

*- the decimal numbers should have a maximum of 4 fractional digits

*- the numbers can be negative

*- if a number is positive then the `+` sign is missing

*- doesn't matter which one of the two numbers is smaller (first number can be bigger than the second one, `"[56 .. 55)"` for instance)

The pattern should match the following:

```
"[10 .. 15)"
"[100 .. 15.2)"
"[10.431 .. 15)"
"[-10.3 .. -5)"
"[-10.4 .. 5.12)"
"[10.4312 .. -5.1232)"
```

I'd also like to obtain the 2 numbers as strings from the string in case the pattern matches:

obtain `"10"` and `"15"` from `"[10 .. 15)"`

obtain `"-10.4"` and `"5.12"` from `"[-10.4 .. 5.12)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^\[(-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?) \.\. (-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?)\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1M42vK/3). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?)` - Group 1: an optional `-`, one to four digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one to four digits
- `\.\.`  - a  `..`  string
- `(-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?)` - Group 2: an optional `-`, one to four digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one to four digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string (use `\z` if you need to check for the very end of string).

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/q9hDGI):

```cs
var texts = new List<string> { "[10 .. 15)", "[100 .. 15.2)", "[10.431 .. 15)", "[-10.3 .. -5)", "[-10.4 .. 5.12)", "[10.4312 .. -5.1232)", "[12345.1234 .. 0)", "[1.23456 .. 0" };
var pattern = new Regex(@"^\[(-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?) \.\. (-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?)\)$");
foreach (var s in texts) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"---- {s} ----");
    var match = pattern.Match(s);
    if (match.Success) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Group 1: {match.Groups[1].Value}, Group 2: {match.Groups[2].Value}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"No match found in '{s}'.");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
---- [10 .. 15) ----
Group 1: 10, Group 2: 15
---- [100 .. 15.2) ----
Group 1: 100, Group 2: 15.2
---- [10.431 .. 15) ----
Group 1: 10.431, Group 2: 15
---- [-10.3 .. -5) ----
Group 1: -10.3, Group 2: -5
---- [-10.4 .. 5.12) ----
Group 1: -10.4, Group 2: 5.12
---- [10.4312 .. -5.1232) ----
Group 1: 10.4312, Group 2: -5.1232
---- [12345.1234 .. 0) ----
No match found in '[12345.1234 .. 0)'.
---- [1.23456 .. 0 ----
No match found in '[1.23456 .. 0'.
```

Comment: The regex you wrote doesn't take into account the fact that the number and its eventual fractional numbers should consists of maximum 4 digits but it will match a number and fractional number of any length. Still, your answer fulfills my need, I mentioned the limit of number of digits in the description just in order to be as specific as I could in the question.

Comment: @ChocapicSz Then use `^\[(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?<!(?:\.?\d){5}) \.\. (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?<!(?:\.?\d){5})\)$`. Note you mentioned that *"the pattern should match the following"* and `[10.431 .. 15)` and `[10.4312 .. -5.1232)` should not match if we take your comment into account.

Comment: With the 2nd and 3rd star (*) I meant the pattern should match `[-1234.5678 .. -1234.5678)` but not the `[12345.1234 .. 0)` or `[1.23456 .. 0)`. Not sure if I could have been more specific.

Comment: @ChocapicSz Aha. So, the int and fractional part can both contain 1-4 digits. Then it is even simpler, `^\[(-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?) \.\. (-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?)\)$`

Comment: Please correct your answer to this one, so it answers the question exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should be fine.

```
^\[-?\d+(?:\.\d+)? \.\. -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)$
```

```cs
var pattern = @"^\[-?\d+(?:\.\d+)? \.\. -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)$";
var inputs = new[]{"[10 .. 15)", "[100 .. 15.2)", "[10.431 .. 15)", "[-10.3 .. -5)", "[-10.4 .. 5.12)", "[10.4312 .. -5.1232)", };
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input + " = " + Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern));
}

// [10 .. 15) = True
// [100 .. 15.2) = True
// [10.431 .. 15) = True
// [-10.3 .. -5) = True
// [-10.4 .. 5.12) = True
// [10.4312 .. -5.1232) = True
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LpswtI

Answer (score 1):

This works (see [this .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hAghf9):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Match m = rx.Match("[123 .. -9876.5432]");
        if (!m.Success )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Match");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine(@"left:  {0}", m.Groups[ "left"  ] );
          Console.WriteLine(@"right: {0}", m.Groups[ "right" ] );
        }
    }
    
    private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex(@"
        ^                      # anchor match at start-of-text
        [[]                    # a left square bracket followed by
          (?<left>             # a named capturing group, containing a number, consisting of
            -?[0-9]{1,4}       # - a mandatory integer portion followed by
            ([.][0-9]{1,4})?   # - an optional fractional portion
          )                    # the whole of which is followed by
        [ ][.][.][ ]           # a separator (' .. '), followed by
          (?<right>            # another named capturing group containing a number, consisting of
            -?[0-9]{1,4}       # - a mandatory integer portion followed by
            ([.][0-9]{1,4})?   # - an optional fractional portion
          )                    # the whole of which is followed by
        \]                     # a right square bracket, followed by
        $                      # end-of-text
      ",
      RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
    );
    
}
```